# How to find out if the message author is an element of my mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

**EDIT: THIS IS FIXED!**
I apparently forgot to reroute my mongoose connection to my Atlas!

I'm making a premium feature in my bot, that allows users to play music. Only thing wrong is that I can't find out how to find the message author's id in the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use await before query like this:

```
 const id = await premiumSchema.findOne({
        userID: message.author.id
 
})
```

after that implement the business logic with `==` if you want to check the type `===`

```
if(id.userID == message.author.id) {
   return message.reply('You are not a premium user!')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) returns promise that will resolve to the document if it's found, otherwise `null`. This means you can simply check if it's not `null`, you don't need to check if the IDs are the same. That's already checked by Mongoose.

Don't forget that you need to `await` the results if you're using promises.

```js
try {
  const premiumMember = await premiumSchema
    .findOne({ userID: message.author.id })
    .exec();

  if (!premiumMember) {
    return message.reply('You are not a premium user!');
  }

  const VC = message.member.voice.channel;

  if (!VC)
    return message.reply(
      'You are not in a VC! Please join one and redo the command!',
    );

  const connection = await VC.join();

  const dispatcher = connection
    .play(ytdl(args[0]))
    .on('finish', () => {
      VC.leave();
      message.channel.send(`${message.author}, your song has ended!`);
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      message.channel.send('There was an error playing this song');
    });
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: I think that worked, but now it's giving me an error: 
```Operation `premium-users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms```

Comment: It seems like it's unrelated to the original problem and there is something with your connection. Check out https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9732

Comment: I changed my DNS to 8.8.8.8 and it still doesn't work